# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to crop only the red area in the given code?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, plot-themes

I am using this code

```
pic1 = GridGraph[{19, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}];
pic2 = Graphics[ {{Inset[Style["text", Black, FontSize -> Scaled[0.1], FontFamily -> "Times"], {5, 5}] } } ]  ;
pic3 = Show[{pic1, pic2}] ;
pic4 = Graphics[ {LightRed, Rotate[Rectangle[{30, 30}, {50, 10}], 45 Degree]} ,ImageSize -> 200 ] ;

Overlay[{pic4, pic3}]
```

and the result is $Fig1$. I have two questions:

**Q1.** How can I ask Mathematica to crop only the red area and give a result like **Fig2**?

**Q2.** Is it possible to control the position of the red square in **Fig1** (the corresponding code **pic4**)? For example, moving it a bit to the right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GridGraph** belongs to the graph theory part of Mathematica and is neither an image nor a graphics. This causes many vicious problems.

**Overlay** can, in fact, overlay multiple graphics; but, the result is neither an image nor a graphics. This causes many vicious problems.

**Show** can overlay graphics properly. It is handy when combining plots, which graphics. The result is a graphic.

**Graphics** overlay earlier subexpressions with the later subexpressions. Therefore, the overlay operation can be done there also.

I leave as a reader's exercise to disasemble the following:

```
picture = Image[Graphics[
    {{LightRed, Translate[Rotate[Rectangle @@ (ConstantArray[5.*Sqrt[1/2], 
           {2, 2}]*{-1, 1}), 45*Degree], {5, 5}]}, 
     {Darker[Blue], (Line[{{0, #1}, {10, #1}}] & ) /@ Range[0, 10], 
      (Line[{{#1, 0}, {#1, 10}}] & ) /@ Range[0, 10], FaceForm[Gray], 
      EdgeForm[Darker[Blue]], Table[Disk[{x + 0.015, y - 0.015}, 0.08], 
       {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]}, Text[Style["Text", Green, Bold, 72, 
       FontFamily -> "Times"], {5, 5}, {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}]]
       
mask = Image[Graphics[{White, Translate[
      Rotate[Rectangle @@ (ConstantArray[5.*Sqrt[1/2], {2, 2}]*{-1, 1}), 
       45*Degree], {5, 5}]}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}, Background -> Black]]
       
ImageApply[If[#2 == {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, #1] & , {picture, mask}]
```

[image: Here are the three images.]

Of course, I may have missed something.